# How to create an Angular component library which can be run with 'ng serve'?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How do I create an Angular component library which include sample/example applications which can be run with `ng serve` or similar command? I ask because although there is some information on structuring such libraries, I don't know how I'm supposed to develop one without ever running it as part of an application.

Comment: This is the tool I use to build Angular component libraries: https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular (or, more specifically, the Angular CLI) does not really support building libraries currently.  An alternative way of developing components separate is to use an alternate application in the same project.  For example, you can create an alternate "main.ts" running only your component, and then create an new entry in `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"apps": [
  {
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [ "assets", "favicon.ico" ],
    "index": "index.html",
    "main": "main.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    "styles": [ "styles/styles.scss" ],
    "scripts": [],
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
    "environments": {
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  },
  {
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [ "assets", "favicon.ico" ],
    "index": "alternate-index.html",
    "main": "alternate-main.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    "styles": [ "styles/styles.scss" ],
    "scripts": [],
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
    "environments": {
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  }
],
```

Note that everything everything besides `index` and `main` are the same. Then you can run the alternate application with:

```
ng serve --app 1
```

Comment: Here from 2021. Though this is exactly what I needed, and is pretty lightweight, it doesn't seem to work anymore. The CLI doesn't know what the `--apps` option is.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a reusable module library `@angular/cli` does not currently support that ability.

However, you can use a useful library called `ng-packagr`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr

1. Install the package:

   ```
   npm install ng-packagr --save-dev
   ```
2. Create an `ng-package.json`

   ```
   {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
      "lib": {
          "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
      }
   }
   ```
3. Add a build target to `package.json`:

   ```
   {
     "scripts": {
        "build": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
      }
   }
   ```
4. Run the build target:

   ```
   npm run build
   ```

The output for the library will be in the `dist` folder.